# equivalent of the default variable doesn't work

Tags: perl

I have a simple server application written in Perl. Here's the working version of it.

```
my $client;
while ($client = $local->accept() ) { 
    print "Connected: ", $client->peerhost(), ":", $client->peerport(), "\n";  

    while (<$client>) {            

        if ($mod_ctr == -1) {
            $num_count = $_;
            init();
        }
        elsif ($mod_sayaci % 2 == 0) {
            $plus_count = $_;
        }
        elsif ($mod_sayaci % 2 == 1) {
            $minus_count = $_;
            eval();
        }

        last if m/^q/gi;
        $mod_sayaci++;
    }
    print "Server awaits..\n"; 
}
```

I'm positive this works perfectly. Now, When I change my code to take a starting char from the client to determine the operation instead of using mod:

```
my $client;

while ($client = $local->accept() ) { 
    print "Connected: ", $client->peerhost(), ":", $client->peerport(), "\n";  

    $input;
    $operation;
    $value;
    while ($input = <$client>) {            

        $operation = substr($input, 0, 1);
        $value     = substr($input, 1, 1);

        print "input: $input \n";
        print "operation: $operation \n";
        print "value: $value \n";

        if ($operation == "r") {
            print "entered r \n";
            $num_count = $value;
            init();
        }
        elsif ($operation == "a") {
            print "entered a \n";
            $plus_count = $value;
        }
        elsif ($operation == "e") {
            print "entered e \n";
            $minus_count = $value;
            eval();
        }
        elsif ($operation == "q") {
            # will quit here
        }
    }
    print "Server awaits..\n"; 
}
```

At the client side, I make the user start with the request which sends `r` as `operation`. Everything works fine until now. After the first input, `input`, `operation` and `value` prints work fine, but it always enters the first `if` and prints `entered r`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have changed from using numbers to using strings to dictate which of the branches should be executed. You need to use `eq` instead of `==` to do string comparisons.

Like this

```
if ($operation eq "r") {
    print "entered r\n";
    $num_count = $value;
    init();
}
```

etc.

Also, you would be doing yourself and anyone who helps you a big favour if you added

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

to the top of every Perl program you write. The *"declarations"*

```
$input;
$operation;
$value;
```

don't do anything useful except as a comment to say which variables are used within the block. Write this

```
my ($input, $operation, $value);
```

and you have done something much more useful.